# Integrating AWS Lambda with Spring app

Tags: java, spring, soap, aws-lambda

I´m having some problems here with my AWS Lambda project.
I have a lambda here which needs to make a call to my other Spring library, and this library makes a SOAP call to our partner.

My lambda is a normal AWS Lambda class and my other app is a Spring project, which has one class with the call to our SOAP partner.

First I was getting some logs from Spring and noticed it was looping the class loading. But still can´t make it work here.

Has anyone already did something like this? Think my Spring library isn´t starting correctly here.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: Here is my code from my Spring library.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.fenix.client"})
```

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fenix.client")
public class Aplicacao extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Aplicacao.class);
    app.setLogStartupInfo(false);
    app.run(args);
}

public Aplicacao() {
    applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Aplicacao.class);
}

public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}
```

}

```
@Component
```

public class TranClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public TranInvoke sendCompassRequest(TranInvoke tranInvoke) {
    System.out.println("compassRequest");
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    JAXBElement<TranInvoke> invoke = factory.createTran(tranInvoke);

    return ((JAXBElement<TranInvoke>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(invoke)).getValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SelectSubjectsInvoke sendCompassRequest(SelectSubjectsInvoke subjectsInvoke) {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    JAXBElement<SelectSubjectsInvoke> invoke = factory.createSelectSubjects(subjectsInvoke);

    return ((JAXBElement<SelectSubjectsInvoke>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(invoke)).getValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SelectContractsInvoke sendCompassRequest(SelectContractsInvoke contractsInvoke) {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    JAXBElement<SelectContractsInvoke> invoke = factory.createSelectContracts(contractsInvoke);

    return ((JAXBElement<SelectContractsInvoke>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(invoke)).getValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SelectTokensInvoke sendCompassRequest(SelectTokensInvoke tokensInvoke) {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    JAXBElement<SelectTokensInvoke> invoke = factory.createSelectTokens(tokensInvoke);

    return ((JAXBElement<SelectTokensInvoke>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(invoke)).getValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SelectTransInvoke sendCompassRequest(SelectTransInvoke transInvoke) {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    JAXBElement<SelectTransInvoke> invoke = factory.createSelectTrans(transInvoke);

    return ((JAXBElement<SelectTransInvoke>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(invoke)).getValue();
}
```

}

```
public class CompassClient {

private TranClient client = null;

public CompassClient() {
    if(client == null) {
        Aplicacao app = new Aplicacao();
        this.client = app.getApplicationContext().getBean(TranClient.class);
    }
}

public TranInvoke sendRequest(TranInvoke tranInvoke) {
    System.out.println("sendRequest");
    return client.sendCompassRequest(tranInvoke);
}

public SelectSubjectsInvoke sendRequest(SelectSubjectsInvoke subjectsInvoke) {
    return client.sendCompassRequest(subjectsInvoke);
}

public SelectContractsInvoke sendRequest(SelectContractsInvoke contractsInvoke) {
    return client.sendCompassRequest(contractsInvoke);
}

public SelectTokensInvoke sendRequest(SelectTokensInvoke tokensInvoke) {
    return client.sendCompassRequest(tokensInvoke);
}

public SelectTransInvoke sendRequest(SelectTransInvoke transInvoke) {
    return client.sendCompassRequest(transInvoke);
}
```

}

> 11:16:21.863 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration.methodValidationPostProcessor()
>   11:16:21.864 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.864 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.864 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.865 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.881 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.881 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter()
>   11:16:21.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.objectNamingStrategy()
>   11:16:21.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanServer()
>   11:16:21.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.884 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.884 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.884 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.885 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.902 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.902 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$TransactionManagementConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.903 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.903 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.903 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.904 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.904 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.904 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.905 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.905 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.921 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.922 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration.platformTransactionManagerCustomizers()
>   11:16:21.922 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.922 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.922 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.923 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.923 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.gson()
>   11:16:21.923 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.923 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.924 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.924 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.924 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.924 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.stringHttpMessageConverter()
>   11:16:21.925 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.925 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.941 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.941 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.942 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.942 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.942 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.943 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
>   11:16:21.943 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.943 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.944 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.945 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.946 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.messageConverters()
>   11:16:21.946 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.946 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.jest.JestAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.946 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.947 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.947 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.jest.JestAutoConfiguration.jestClient()
>   11:16:21.947 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.948 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.948 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties' in any property source
>   11:16:21.948 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.info.build.location' in any property source
>   11:16:21.948 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.949 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.949 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.949 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.949 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.950 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.950 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.950 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.950 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration.multipartConfigElement()
>   11:16:21.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration.multipartResolver()
>   11:16:21.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
>   11:16:21.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
>   11:16:21.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfiguration.restTemplateBuilder()
>   11:16:21.952 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration'
>   11:16:21.964 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced com.fenix.client.Aplicacao; enhanced class name is: com.fenix.client.Aplicacao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e93fe0
>   11:16:21.964 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'aplicacao' existing class 'com.fenix.client.Aplicacao' with enhanced class 'com.fenix.client.Aplicacao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e93fe0'
>   11:16:21.964 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced com.fenix.client.SoapClientConfig; enhanced class name is: com.fenix.client.SoapClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd76c1d
>   11:16:21.964 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'soapClientConfig' existing class 'com.fenix.client.SoapClientConfig' with enhanced class 'com.fenix.client.SoapClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd76c1d'
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58e673d3
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58e673d3'
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58e673d3
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58e673d3'
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21272933
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21272933'
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66104344
>   11:16:21.965 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66104344'
>   11:16:21.966 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3c3812b
>   11:16:21.966 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3c3812b'
>   11:16:21.966 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration; enhanced class name is: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95cf1eba
>   11:16:21.966 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' existing class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' with enhanced class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95cf1eba'

Comment: It might beneficial if you provided a [minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the logs.

Comment: just added my classes to question...